# Premultiply paths in SVG files

Tags: node.js, svg, npm

I have a bunch of simple SVG files that basically look like this:

```
<svg>
  <g transform="…">
    <path d="…"/>
    <path d="…"/>
    …
  </g>
</svg>
```

The `transform` is also very basic, but different for each file: just a `translate`, possibly also a `scale` or both combined in a 2D matrix.

How can I quickly, simply and automatically apply the transformation to all paths in all files? I have Inkscape and svgo or anything else from NPM available.

Comment: SVGO with the standard params should suffice. If you want to test beforehand you can upload a sample file at https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ and see what comes out from the other end.

Comment: So I thought, too, but regardless of the setting for `convertTransform`, the transform remains.